# Scraping data from a GroupGrid

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to scrape and analyze the input to a when2meet table.

Here's a sample: http://www.when2meet.com/?4474391-IBuBA

[image: A screenshot of a GroupGrid from when2meet. There are two visual sections. The right is titled "Group's Availability" and shows a 4x5 grid of hour-long time slots during the week (columns are labelled with the weekdays Monday to Friday, rows are labelled with an hour, from 9 AM to Noon). Grids are colored in a gradient from white (only 1 of the 10 respondents is available) to dark green (8 of ten are available). There is a mouse pointer depicted hovering over "Monday, 11:00 - 11:30 AM", and the details of who is available for this slot are dynamically displayed in the left portion of the screenshot. This left section is titled "7/10 Available" and lists the 7 users responding "Available" in the left column and the 3 "Unavailable" in the right column.]

The table gives a rapid visual overview of each group member's availability; I want to extract this to R to do some analysis, but am coming up short.

Very short, in fact; I've only gotten so far as extracting the main page element. The output (to me) is gibberish:

```
library(rvest)

url <- "http://www.when2meet.com/?4474391-IBuBA"

grid <- html(url) %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="GroupGrid"]')
```

`grid` looks like this:

```
<div style="font-size:0px;vertical-align:top;"><div id="GroupTime279816300" onmouseover="ShowSlot(279816300);" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;*display:inline;zoom:1;width:44px;height:9px;font-size:0px;border-left: 1px black solid;background: #c5e2b6;"><script><![CDATA[
Col[TimeOfSlot.indexOf(279816300)] = 0;
Row[TimeOfSlot.indexOf(279816300)] = 23;
]]></script></div>
<div id="GroupTime279902700" onmouseover="ShowSlot(279902700);" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;*display:inline;zoom:1;width:44px;height:9px;font-size:0px;border-left: 1px black solid;background: #8ac56d;"><script><![CDATA[
Col[TimeOfSlot.indexOf(279902700)] = 1;
Row[TimeOfSlot.indexOf(279902700)] = 23;
]]></script></div>
<div id="GroupTime279989100" onmouseover="ShowSlot(279989100);" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;*display:inline;zoom:1;width:44px;height:9px;font-size:0px;border-left: 1px black solid;background: #c5e2b6;"><script><![CDATA[
Col[TimeOfSlot.indexOf(279989100)] = 2;
Row[TimeOfSlot.indexOf(279989100)] = 23;
]]></script>
```

I basically see nothing of use to me here; it may as well be Urdu. And I wasn't able to find anything on Google or SO about scraping GroupGrid tables.

Does anyone have any idea of how to proceed?

Ideally, I'd have an output `data.table` (`data.frame`, if you must) of the form:

```
output
#        id    slot available
# 1: user_1  M 9:00      TRUE
# 2: user_1  T 9:30     FALSE
# 3: user_1 W 10:00      TRUE
# 4: user_1 R 10:30      TRUE
# 5: user_2  M 9:00      TRUE
# 6: user_2  T 9:30     FALSE
# 7: user_2 W 10:00      TRUE
# 8: user_2 R 10:30     FALSE
```

(the exact format of the `slot` column is not important, nor does it need to be one column -- could, if easier, be `day` and `time`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
library(data.table)

script <- html("http://www.when2meet.com/?4474391-IBuBA") %>%
  html_nodes("script:contains('PeopleNames')") %>% html_text()

f <- function(regex) {
  m <- regmatches(script, gregexpr(regex, script))[[1]]
  #faster than transposing with `t`
  setDT(transpose(lapply(regmatches(m, regexec(regex, m)), "[", -1)))[]
}
slots <- f("TimeOfSlot\\[(\\d+)\\]=(\\d+);")
users <- f( "PeopleNames\\[(\\d+)\\] = '([^']+)';PeopleIDs\\[\\d+\\] = (\\d+);")
avails <- f("AvailableAtSlot\\[(\\d+)]\\.push\\((\\d+)\\);")

DT <- melt(dcast(avails, V2~V1, 
                 fun.aggregate = function(x) length(x) > 0,
                 value.var = "V2"), id.vars = "V2",
           variable.name = "timeslot", value.name = "available")

DT[users, id := i.V2, on = c(V2 = "V3")]
DT[slots, time := format(as.POSIXct(as.integer(
  i.V2), origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT"), "%a %H:%M"),
  on = c(timeslot = "V1")]

DT[ , c("V2", "timeslot") := NULL]

DT[time == "Mon 11:00" & available]
#    available      id      time
# 1:      TRUE  user_1 Mon 11:00
# 2:      TRUE  user_2 Mon 11:00
# 3:      TRUE  user_3 Mon 11:00
# 4:      TRUE  user_4 Mon 11:00
# 5:      TRUE  user_5 Mon 11:00
# 6:      TRUE  user_7 Mon 11:00
# 7:      TRUE user_10 Mon 11:00

DT[time == "Mon 11:00" & !available]
#    available     id      time
# 1:     FALSE user_6 Mon 11:00
# 2:     FALSE user_8 Mon 11:00
# 3:     FALSE user_9 Mon 11:00
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the improved screenshot. I won't get a chance to confirm this works until tomorrow (looks excellent!) How did you know the `TimeOfSlot` RHS could be converted to `POSIXct`? And did you just guess-and-verify the origin, timezone, etc?

Comment: All data is in the JavaScript of the page - I looked for "user_1" and was there. Yes, converting timestamps to datetime objects was trial and error (the default, CET, was one hour ahead, so I set GMT explicitly; and the origin is a common origin, so it was my first guess).The screenshot is to show that the result of "Mon, 11 am" matches the output of `subset`. :-)

Comment: Awesome! The `regexec` part in particular is beautiful. Thanks. I've edited to reflect more my style (and I believe speed it up)

Comment: This just worked for the exact same problem right out off the shelf, thanks so much. In the dumpster fire that is 2020, this is the first positive thing that has happened.

Comment: Can't emphasize how great it is that this works off the shelf.

I added a time-zone function for my own convenience, which other's might find useful: 

```DT[slots, time := format(lubridate::with_tz(as.POSIXct(as.integer(
  i.V2), origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT"), "America/New_York"), "%a %H:%M"),
  on = c(timeslot = "V1")]```